# LVM snapshot keeps changing file timestamps

Tags: lvm, snapshot

I searched the web but did not find any info about this. I'm mounting an LVM snapshot and I notice the timestamps of the files there keep changing. I though LVM snapshot was a one time freeze in time w/ write on copy of the original partition, so the timestamps should not change.

Of course now tar is giving me an error saying the "file changed as we read it" which I think comes from the timestamps being changed.

Any insights?

Comment: Are you saying that you mount a snapshot under, e.g., /mnt and then create a tarball of /mnt filesystem during which you get the "file changed as we read it?"

Comment: yes, exactly, do timestamps of snapshot files change?

Answer (score 1):

The snapshot will keep changing. The underlying filesystem will not. Make backups from that instead.

Comment: I dont understand. I can i make a backup from the filesystem without having to mount the snapshot in /mnt

Comment: You don't mount the snapshot in `/mnt`. You mount the snapshot where you normally would, and you mount the underlying filesystem read-only in `/mnt`.

Comment: still dont get it. im using the procedure for backups as explained here:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/21/using-lvm-for-mysql-backup-and-replication-setup/

Comment: That article has it backwards. Mount the snapshot in place, and backup the underlying filesystem.

Comment: but the underlying filesystem is changing cause the tables are unlocked... thats the all purpose of having the snapshot, to avoid table locking for more than n seconds

Comment: Wait, that article is from 2006. That means that it would be using LVM1. Are you sure that *you're* using LVM1? It certainly sounds to me as though you're using LVM2.

Comment: @Ignacio - I don't understand your answer.  The whole idea of LVM snapshots (like other types of snapshot) is to provide a frozen, point-in-time view of the original LV.  The LVM HOWTO confirms that's how things work: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshotintro.html - LVM1 had read-only snapshots, while LVM2 has read-write as well (so you can clone and then do something to the filesystem).

Answer (score 0):

So apparently lvm1 timestamps the mtime on files instead of the snapshot creation time:
http://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2005-April/msg00039.html

this explains why tar is complaining. Any way i can make tar ignore this?

Comment: just realized i can do --warning=no-file-changed but only works for tar v>=1.23 ;(

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that no one can write to your snapshot while you run your backup, try mounting it read-only:

```
mount -o ro <snapshot-device> /mnt
```

**EDIT**

If the snapshot is already mounted, try this instead:

```
mount -o remount,ro <snapshot-device> /mnt
```

Comment: it's giving me a mount error "already mounted" if i give that option. besides how would the timestamps be updated if it's read only?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try the `remount` option. I don't understand the rest of your comment. What timestamps do you think should be updated?